# How to stop redirecting to next page when validation fails?

Tags: asp.net

I have put validation on controls like TextBox on a Form in ASP.NET. When validation fails it is still redirecting to next page. How do I resolve this?

```
<div class="inp-cont forget-success-hide">
   <label for="inputFirstName">Name <span class="text-error"
      style="Color:Red">*</span></label>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="signininput" ID="txtname" placeholder="Enter Your
      Name"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
      ValidationGroup="rg" ErrorMessage="Please enter Your Name"
      ControlToValidate="txtname"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <br/>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3"
      runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtname" ErrorMessage="Only
      alphabets are allowed" ForeColor="Red"
      ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+" > </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
<div class="inp-cont forget-success-hide">
   <label for="inputFirstName">Email <span class="text-error"
      style="Color:Red">*</span></label>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="signininput" ID="txtemail" placeholder="Enter Your Email
      Id"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
      ValidationGroup="rg" ErrorMessage="Please enter email id"
      ControlToValidate="txtemail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <br />
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rv" runat="server"
      ControlToValidate="txtemail" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="rg"
      ErrorMessage="Enter vaild email id"
      ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
   <asp:Label ID="lblemail" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div class="inp-cont forget-success-hide">
   <label for="inputLastName">Gender <span class="text-error"
      style="Color:Red">*</span></label>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" class="signininput" Width="100%">
      <asp:ListItem Text="Select Gender" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
      ValidationGroup="rg" ErrorMessage="Please select gender"
      InitialValue="0"
      ControlToValidate="ddlGender"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<div class="inp-cont forget-success-hide">
   <label for="inputEMail">Password <span class="text-error"
      style="Color:Red">*</span></label>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="signininput" ID="txtpwd" MaxLength="20" TextMode="Password"
      placeholder="Enter Your Password"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
      ValidationGroup="rg" ErrorMessage="Please enter password" 
      ControlToValidate="txtpwd"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<div class="inp-cont forget-success-hide">
   <label for="inputEMail">Confirm Password <span class="text-error"
      style="Color:Red">*</span></label>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="signininput" ID="txtcpwd" MaxLength="20" TextMode="Password"
      placeholder="Enter Confirm Password"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
      ValidationGroup="rg" ErrorMessage="Please enter confirm password" 
      ControlToValidate="txtcpwd"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <br />
   <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmp" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="rg"
      ErrorMessage="Password does not match" ControlToCompare="txtpwd"
      ControlToValidate="txtcpwd"  Type="String"
      Operator="Equal"></asp:CompareValidator>
   <asp:Label ID="lblpwd" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div class="inp-cont forget-success-hide">
   <label for="inputMob">Mobile No <span class="text-error" style="Color:Red">*</span></label>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="10" class="signininput"
      onkeypress="inputNumberOnly(event)" ID="txtmobno" placeholder="Enter
      Your Mobile"></asp:TextBox>
   <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
      runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtmobno"
                                                                              ValidationGroup="rg"  ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid
      phone number"
                                                                               ValidationExpression="^[7-9][0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator><br
      />--%>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
      runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtmobno"
      ValidationGroup="rg"  ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid
      mobile number"
      ValidationExpression="^[789]\d{9}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
   <br
      />
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
      ValidationGroup="rg" ErrorMessage="Please enter mobile number" 
      ControlToValidate="txtmobno"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

Comment: Format your question. It's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

properly use validation group and in button control add validation group and check that validation group name should be same in button control and other controls also where we have used asp.net validation control